# AWS CodeBuild Webhook - CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I know we can enable webhook from AWS Web Console but Can we enable CodeBuild webhook from cloudformation template in yml?

**codebuild.yml**

```
Resources:
  
  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    DependsOn:
      - CodeBuildSourceCredential
    .
    .
    Properties:
      Source:
        Type: GITHUB
        Location: https://github.com/path/project.git
        BuildSpec: buildspec.yml
      .
      .

      Triggers:
        Webhook: true
        FilterGroups:
          - - Type: EVENT
              Pattern: PUSH

  CodeBuildSourceCredential:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential'
    Properties: 
      Token: '<TokenString>'
      ServerType: GITHUB
      AuthType: PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I tried to create this stack but it seems not work, stack failed with this error

```
Failed to call CreateWebhook, reason: Unable to create webhook at this time. Please try again later. (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400; Error Code: OAuthProviderException; Request ID: xxxxxx-5ddf-xxxx-88a1-xxxxxx; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: Did you auth (for ex by username/password) on Console yet?

Comment: yes i did, I generated PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN and provided it on source section

Comment: Your CodeBuild's `Source` block is missing the [Auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-source.html#cfn-codebuild-project-source-auth) property, where you reference the `SourceCredential`. Also, can you confirm that the Github user related to the access token has proper permissions to create a webhook for that repository?

Answer (score 4):

An example CloudFormation template snippet is as follows:

```
Resources:
  Project:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: CFN-Project
      # Other properties ............................................
      Source:
        Location: https://github.com/shariqmus/private-repo.git
        Type: GITHUB
        Auth:
          Type: OAUTH
          Resource: !Ref GitHubToken # Personal Access Token
      SourceVersion: master   # Branch name
      Triggers:
        Webhook: true
        FilterGroups:
          - - Type: EVENT
              Pattern: PUSH
              ExcludeMatchedPattern: false
            - Type: HEAD_REF
              Pattern: refs/heads/master # 'master' is Branch name
              ExcludeMatchedPattern: false
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is the only good example of CodeBuild Triggers in Cloudformation.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message it seems you haven't setup [AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-sourcecredential.html), nor your question provide any details about the use of this resource.

The `AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential` is needed for  GitHub, GitHub Enterprise, or Bitbucket:

> Information about the **credentials** for a GitHub, GitHub Enterprise, or Bitbucket repository. We strongly recommend that you use AWS Secrets Manager to store your credentials.

Once you create `AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential`, you have to make `CodeBuildProject` **dependent** on the credentials. For example:

```
  MySourceCreds:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential'
    # other parameters

  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    DependsOn: MySourceCreds
    # other parameters
```

Comment: I have that "SourceCredential" Resource and "dependsOn" exactly as you mentioned

Comment: @BheshRajSejawal Could you then please update your question with all relevant details. Your current `CodeBuildProject` does not show any DependsOn nor `AWS::CodeBuild::SourceCredential`.